# Running Database Script Error SQL Server/ Report Server

Tags: sql-server, server, sql-server-2014, power-bi-report-server, reportserver

I keep receiving this error and am unable to fix it - can anyone help?

- Before I start the below instructions, I set up SQL Server 2014 on my computer.

What I did before?

- I change **Use built-in account** to **Network Service**;
- Then in **Web Service URL** section, I changed default IP-ADRESS setting **All Assigned(recommended)** into protocol form, and also
  TCP Port --> 80 to 800;
- After that, I came to **Database** section. I clicked on ***Change Database button*** --> ***Create a new report server database***.

At the end of creating process I receive this error message:

[image: I receive that error message all the time...]

[image: Click on the link to see error message]

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: Also that looks like standard SQL Server Reporting Services - Not Power BI Report Server.

Comment: There you go - your error message tells you the problem - the account you are running the installer under doesn't have sufficient permissions to create a new database.

Comment: I just edit my question and added it to the end. Sorry, I forgot to post the actual error.

Comment: @DaleK so sir can I give that permission to my self by changing my role under Login Properties in SQL Server or not? I glad you are back very fast btw :) Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database user must be a member of **dbcreator** server role to create the **ReportServer** and **ReportServerTemp** databases.

To add a member to `dbcreator`, you must be a member of that role, or be a member of the `sysadmin`.

With the following script you can add permission required:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE dbcreator ADD MEMBER YourDatabaseUser;
```

Comment: I did sir, just created my database but now the problem is I can't reach my WEB PORTAL unless I change IP-ADRESS to my local computer name.

Comment: You should configure a web portal. The documentation is in the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-web-portal?view=sql-server-ver15